# How can i fix the navbar? Problem with height

Tags: javascript, html, css

i'm trying to put my menu horizontally on mobile version like that:

[image]

But, when i modified the values to:

.left-side (white): 
width: 100%
height: 40vh

and

.menu (right side black):
width: 100%;
height: 60vh;

But when I do, the menu breaks. The right menu is at the top.

I have seen that if I change the height by 100% for the nav, it works. But then when I go back to desktop version, when using the element inspector, the menu is at the top all the time (the layer) (I can't select texts). I tried with z-index and nothing. The nav i think should be height: 80px in desktop and 100vh but i don't know.

CodePen here: https://codepen.io/ZeR0ByTe/pen/KKdzmJV?editors=0100

```
        <nav id="navbar">
        <div id="left-side" class="left-side">
            <div class="profile">
                <img class="picture" src="img/foto.jpg" alt="">
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="menu" class="menu">
            <a href="#">Home</a>
            <a href="#">Education</a>
            <a href="#">Experience</a>
            <a href="#">Languages</a>
            <a href="#">Skills</a>
            <a href="#">Portfolio</a>
            <a href="#">References</a>
            <a href="#">Contact me</a>
        </div>

        <div class="containerIconMobile">
            <div id="toggle" class="iconMobile">

            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <header>
        <div class="overlay"></div>
        <div class="header-content">
            <div class="content">
                <h1 class="main-title">Diego J. <span>Franchina</span></h1>
                <h2 class="second-title">Web <span>Designer</span> / Web <span>Developer</span></h2>
            </div>

            <div class="social-icons">
                <i class="social-icon fa fa-facebook-official fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                <i class="social-icon fa fa-instagram fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                <i class="social-icon fa fa-linkedin fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                <i class="social-icon fa fa-github fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>

    <main>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="title-section">
                <h2>EDUCATION</h2>
                <hr class="line-titles">
            </div>

            <div class="container-education">
                <div class="education-schools">
                    <h3 class="item-school">Instituto Superior Argentino de Computación</h3>
                    <h4 class="item-title-school">Analista de Sistemas</h4>
                    <p class="item-description-school">Legalizado y Certificado en el Ministerio de Relaciones Exteriores para poder trabajar en el Exterior.</p>
                    <hr class="line-separator">
                </div>
                <div class="education-years">
                    <p class="item-description-school">2009 - 2012</p>
                </div>
                <hr class="line-separator">
            </div>

            <div class="container-education">
                <div class="education-schools">
                    <h3 class="item-school">Nuestra Sra. del Buen y Perpetuo Socorro</h3>
                    <h4 class="item-title-school">Bachillerato</h4>
                    <p class="item-description-school">Perito Mercantil.</p>
                    <hr class="line-separator">
                </div>
                <div class="education-years">
                    2009 - 2012
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="container">
            <div class="title-section">
                <h2>EDUCATION</h2>
                <hr class="line-titles">
            </div>

            <div class="container-education">
                <div class="education-schools">
                    <h3 class="item-school">Instituto Superior Argentino de Computación</h3>
                    <h4 class="item-title-school">Analista de Sistemas</h4>
                    <p class="item-description-school">Legalizado y Certificado en el Ministerio de Relaciones Exteriores para poder trabajar en el Exterior.</p>
                    <hr class="line-separator">
                </div>
                <div class="education-years">
                    <p class="item-description-school">2009 - 2012</p>
                </div>
                <hr class="line-separator">
            </div>

            <div class="container-education">
                <div class="education-schools">
                    <h3 class="item-school">Nuestra Sra. del Buen y Perpetuo Socorro</h3>
                    <h4 class="item-title-school">Bachillerato</h4>
                    <p class="item-description-school">Perito Mercantil.</p>
                    <hr class="line-separator">
                </div>
                <div class="education-years">
                    2009 - 2012
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="container">
            <div class="title-section">
                <h2>EDUCATION</h2>
                <hr class="line-titles">
            </div>

            <div class="container-education">
                <div class="education-schools">
                    <h3 class="item-school">Instituto Superior Argentino de Computación</h3>
                    <h4 class="item-title-school">Analista de Sistemas</h4>
                    <p class="item-description-school">Legalizado y Certificado en el Ministerio de Relaciones Exteriores para poder trabajar en el Exterior.</p>
                    <hr class="line-separator">
                </div>
                <div class="education-years">
                    <p class="item-description-school">2009 - 2012</p>
                </div>
                <hr class="line-separator">
            </div>

            <div class="container-education">
                <div class="education-schools">
                    <h3 class="item-school">Nuestra Sra. del Buen y Perpetuo Socorro</h3>
                    <h4 class="item-title-school">Bachillerato</h4>
                    <p class="item-description-school">Perito Mercantil.</p>
                    <hr class="line-separator">
                </div>
                <div class="education-years">
                    2009 - 2012
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </main>
```

CSS

```
$grey: #222222;
$secondTitle: #999999;
$pink: #fd5c63;
$white: #ffffff;
$black: #000000;
$primary-color: #ffc20e;

* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
}

html {
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

span {
    color: $primary-color;
    font-weight: bolder;
}

body {
    color: $white;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: $grey;
}

    header {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100vh;
        position: relative;
        background: url(../img/wall2.jpg);
        background-position: center;
        background-size: cover;

        .overlay {
            background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            z-index: 0;

        }

        .header-content {
            width: 40%;
            height: 100vh;
            position: absolute;
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
            justify-content: center;
            padding: 50px;
            text-align: center;
            z-index: 1;

            .main-title {
                font-size: 54px;
                font-weight: bold;
                text-shadow: 4px 4px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
            }

            .second-title {
                text-shadow: 4px 4px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
                padding: 20px;
            }

            .social-icons {
                display: flex;
                justify-content: space-between;
                padding: 10px;

                .social-icon {
                    text-shadow: 4px 4px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
                    padding: 10px;
                    transition: 1s ease;

                    &:hover {
                        color: $primary-color;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    nav {
        display: flex;
        width: 100%;
        height: 80px;
        color: $black;
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        z-index: 4;

        .left-side {
            width: 40%;
            height: 100vh;
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
            background-color: rgba(119, 116, 116, 0.95);
            position: absolute;
            left: -100%;
            transition: 1s ease;
            z-index: 5;

            &.left-effect {
                left: 0 !important;
            }

            .profile {

                .picture {
                    border-radius: 50%;
                    width: 200px;
                    height: 200px;
                    object-fit: cover;
                    border: 5px solid $primary-color;

                }
            }
        }

        .menu {
            position: absolute;
            right: -100%;
            width: 60%;
            height: 100vh;
            background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
            transition: 1s ease;

            &.right-effect {
                right: 0;
            }

            a {
                display: flex;
                flex-direction: column;
                text-decoration: none;
                color: #999999;
                font-size: 24px;
                font-weight: bolder;
                letter-spacing: 5px;
                padding: 10px 0;
                transition: 1s;
                text-transform: uppercase;

                &:hover {
                    color: $primary-color;
                }
            }
        }

        .containerIconMobile {
            position: absolute;
            top: 30px;
            right: 30px;

            .iconMobile {
                width: 30px;
                height: 30px;
                position: relative;

                cursor: pointer;

                &:before {
                    content: '';
                    position: absolute;
                    top: 7px;
                    width: 100%;
                    height: 2px;
                    background-color: $white;
                    transition: 1s ease;
                }

                &:after {
                    content: '';
                    position: absolute;
                    bottom: 7px;
                    width: 100%;
                    height: 2px;
                    background-color: $white;
                    transition: 1s ease;
                }

                &.active {

                    &:before {
                        top: 50%;
                        left: 50%;
                        transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(45deg);
                    }

                    &:after {
                        top: 50%;
                        left: 50%;
                        transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(-45deg);
                    }
                }
            }


        }

    }

main {
  .container {
    width: 98%;
    height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    z-index: 4;

    .title-section {
      text-align: center;
      font-size: 24px;
      margin: 20px;
    }

    .line-titles {
      border: 3px solid #ffc20e;
      width: 25%;
      margin: 10px auto;
    }
  }

  .container-education {
    width: 70%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
  }

  .education-schools {
    width: 70%;
    margin-bottom: 30px;

    .item-school {
      font-size: 24px;
    }

    .item-title-school {
      font-size: 22px;
      color: #999999;
    }

    .item-description-school {
      font-size: 20px;
      margin: 10px 0;
    }

    .line-separator {
      border: 3px solid #999999;
      width: 25%;
      margin: 30px auto 0 auto;
    }
  }

  .education-years {
    width: 30%;
    font-size: 20px;
    text-align: right;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 480px) {
    body {
        header {

            .header-content {
                width: 100%;

                .main-title {
                    font-size: 35px;
                }

                .second-title {
                    font-size: 18px;
                }
            }


        }

        nav {

            .left-side {
                top: 0;
                background-color: rgba(119, 116, 116, .9);
                z-index: 2;

                .profile {
                    .picture {
                        width: 120px;
                        height: 120px;
                    }
                }
            }

            .menu {
                z-index: 2;
                background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
                right: -100% !important;
                // bottom: -825%;

                &.right-effect {
                    right: 0 !important;
                }

                a {
                    font-size: 18px;
                }
            }

            .containerIconMobile {
                z-index: 4;

                .iconMobile {
                    &:before {
                        background-color: $white;
                    }

                    &:after {
                        background-color: $white;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        main {
            .container-education {
                width: 90%;
                flex-direction: column;
            }
        }

    }
}
```

JS

```
const toggle = document.getElementById("toggle");
const leftSide = document.getElementById("left-side");
const navbar = document.getElementById("navbar");
const menu = document.getElementById("menu");

toggle.addEventListener("click",  () =>{
    // navbar.classList.toggle("active")
    toggle.classList.toggle("active");
    leftSide.classList.toggle("left-effect");
    menu.classList.toggle("right-effect");;
})
```

Hope someone can help and undestand my post. If not i will try be more specific

Thanks

Comment: Thanks for your advice @AymanMorsy, is my first project with SASS. I have read nested selectors is the correct form. I read here: https://sass-lang.com/documentation/syntax and in SCSS is like my post. Now i'm confused. THanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use below code in your media query

I believe for nav toggle btn to work you need to add little `z-index` to it

```
nav .left-side {
    width: 100%;
    height: 40vh;
}

nav .menu {
    width: 100%;
    height: 60vh;
    margin-top: 45vh;
}

nav .containerIconMobile {
    z-index: 9;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Rahul!!! margin-top it was what I needed!! But i don't understand why :S. If you could explain me, i will appreciate. THANKS again!

Comment: @ZeR0ByTe since your `#left-side` and `#menu` are `position absolute` so in order to appear one below another we have to add bottom one either `top` or `margin-top` of height of `#left-side` or greater than that so it appear below `#left-side`